# How to run Gtest in powershell with set debug environment

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2019, googletest, cicd

Currenlty I am using Visual Studio community edition and Gtest.

When I run my test using the Visual Studio debug, my test are running fine

[image: Debug environment]

But when I build the solution and run my test fail.

[image: command]

Is there a way I can pass the PATH environment to the command I am runnig?

Try to set the PATH on powershell so it would load while running the command.

Comment: Show a [mcve]. I guess PATH has nothing to do there. Look for working directory.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I will make sure next question I add min reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @273k I was able to solve my problem.

The reason this test did not pass on the command line, was due to this was being run on a different folder.

Once I moved the relevant support files in the same folder the test started to pass